# Elasticsearch NEST Unit Test a Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm having problems testing a service with NEST Elasticsearch. I have the following test class:

```
public class ProductSearchServiceShould
{
  private readonly Mock<IElasticClient> _elasticClientMock;
  private readonly Mock<IHit<Product>> _hitMock;
  private readonly Mock<ISearchResponse<Product>> _searchResponseMock;
  private readonly IProductSearchService _productSearchService;

  public ProductSearchServiceShould()
  {
      _elasticClientMock = new Mock<IElasticClient>();
      _hitMock = new Mock<IHit<Product>>();
      _searchResponseMock = new Mock<ISearchResponse<Product>>();
      _productSearchService = new ProductSearchService(_optionsMock.Object);
  }

  [Fact]
  public void GetProducts_ValidSearchRequest_ReturnsISearchResponseProduct()
  {
      // Arrange
      var mockValidProducts = MockProducts.Valid;
      var hits = new List<IHit<Product>>
      {
          _hitMock.Object
      };

      _searchResponseMock.Setup(x => x.Documents).Returns(mockValidProducts);
      _searchResponseMock.Setup(x => x.HitsMetadata.Hits).Returns(hits);

      _elasticClientMock.Setup(x => x
        .Search(It.IsAny<Func<SearchDescriptor<Product>, ISearchRequest>>()))
        .Returns(_searchResponseMock.Object);

      // Act
      // var result = _elasticClientMock.Object.Search<Product>(s => s);
      var result = _productSearchService.GetProducts(_elasticClientMock.Object, MockSearchRequest.Valid);

      // Assert
      Assert.NotNull(result);
      Assert.Equal(mockValidProducts.Count, result.Documents.Count);
      Assert.Equal(1, result.HitsMetadata.Hits.Count);
  }
}
```

I don't unterstand why I can't get my _productSearchService.GetProducts() method to return something. The result is always null even though I mocked the client and all used services in the class.

```
var result = _elasticClientMock.Object.Search<Product>(s => s);
```

The line above works but it's not really useful if I want to test the method itself.

The method being called is:

```
public ISearchResponse<Product> GetProducts(IElasticClient client,
    SearchRequest searchRequest)
{
    var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<Product>();
    searchDescriptor.Index("products")
        .Sort(s => s.Ascending(product => product.Name.Suffix("keyword")))
        .From(searchRequest.Limit * searchRequest.Page).Size(searchRequest.Limit);
    return client.Search<Product>(searchDescriptor);
}
```

Comment: You may want to set your mock to strict. So you know that the setup you did is actually correct and used. At least the _elasticClientMock Mock.

Comment: @Ralf if I use strict I get "All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup." Still doesn't really tell me what else I have to mock since all I really need are the documents which are being returned

Comment: If your service only calls search on the nest client you now know that the setup for search is wrong. If you have multiple calls to the nest client only setting up the one search endpoint would have been wrong anyway. But now you can simply debug your test. When you have setup your debugger to stop when an exception has been thrown you will now know exactly what call is the problem.

Comment: I've added the method above which is being called from the test for better understanding. @Ralf

Comment: You mocked `Search` but your service calls `Search<Product>` .

Comment: The Search<Product> in the _elasticClientMock.Setup is redundant if we're talking about the same part

Comment: That's the one. And without knowing to much about NEST i assume it has a generic and a non generic version of search. In certain code parts the generic parameter doesn't need to be named because it can be be deduced from the code but in a mock setup it must be named. So i'm pretty sure it isn't redundant.

Comment: In general yes but the type is already defined by the _searchResponseMock which is of type Product